# why getting formula field using multiple objects information

Tags: visualforce

I am writing formula field like this:

```
club62__Miscellaneous_fee__r.club62__Bartender_Fee__c + 
club62__Miscellaneous_fee__r.club62__Box_Handling_Fee__c + 
club62__Miscellaneous_fee__r.club62__Cashier_Fee__c + 
club62__Miscellaneous_fee__r.club62__Chef_Fee__c + 
club62__Miscellaneous_fee__r.club62__Corkage__c + 
club62__Miscellaneous_fee__r.club62__Flowers_Fee__c + 
club62__Miscellaneous_fee__r.club62__Kosher_Delivery_Fee__c + 
club62__Miscellaneous_fee__r.club62__Photocopies_Fee__c + 
club62__Miscellaneous_fee__r.club62__Rentals_Fee__c
```

i need to store these field values in a single field of master object(using master-detail relationship).

and this is not working from starting.
is something wrong?? if yes then what?

i'm little new to salesforce...can anybody please help

Comment: You can't reference child field in Parent object using this approach. if they are number field then you can create roll up summary fields

Comment: if i use roll up summary... then it will give update result each time when a child record will be created for same id?  Like i am created 3 child records for a same parent id then there is something i can sum up the records?

Comment: Yes if you add new child then it will automatically calculate that.

Answer (score 2):

Try creating two separate [formula fields](https://developer.salesforce.com/page/An_Introduction_to_Formulas), one on the child, and another on the parent.

On the child, add all the fields you need to represent expenses (`club62__Bartender_Fee__c`, `club62__Box_Handling_Fee__c`), and add them together. This should get you a total expense per child record.

To get all the expenses from child records on the parent record, create a [roll-up summary field](https://help.salesforce.com/HTViewHelpDoc?id=fields_about_roll_up_summary_fields.htm) on the parent object, which uses the expense field previously created. Every time you request a summary field from salesforce, salesforce performs the calculations required to get an up to date value of the field, by obtaining the value of the field specified for all child records, and then performing the operation requested (in this case, `SUM`).

If you want to sum each child field separately, you can create multiple roll-up summary fields, but there is a limit of 25 per object (Changed in [Winter '16](https://success.salesforce.com/ideaview?id=08730000000BqY2AAK)).